# Supposed to get Grid of 3 images

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am supposed to get grid of 3 images but what i get is a correct first row of images and the second row of images is not displaying properly.Please look at the image attached to get what i am trying to explain. Am i missing something?

```
<?php 
    // start first row
    echo "<hr class='margin-bottom-40'>";
    echo "<div class='row blog blog-medium margin-bottom-40'>";
    foreach ($m->result() as $row)  {
        $Player=$row->image;
        echo "<div class='col-sm-4'>";
        echo "<div class='news-v2-badge'><img class='img-responsive' style='' src='http://opunletter.com/" .  $Player . "'";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<p><span>23</span><small>Jan</small></p>";
        echo "<div class='post-caption'>";
        echo "<ul class='post-inline block-grid-v1-add-info'>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> 34039</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-up'></i> 451</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-down'></i> 863</a></li>";
        echo "</ul>"; 
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='news-v2-desc'>";
        echo "<h3><a href='#'>Reading Some Books</a></h3>";
        echo "<small>By Admin | California, US | In <a href='#'>Art</a></small>";
        echo "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio.</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

[image]

Comment: its because your 2 items in first row is taller than the 3rd item in first row.

Comment: Use CSS "min-height"

Comment: thanks.. to both of u..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. it will create div row in every 3 items;

```
 <?php 
$count=0;
    // start first row
        echo "<hr class='margin-bottom-40'>";
        echo "<div class='row blog blog-medium margin-bottom-40'>";
echo '<div class="row">'
        foreach ($m->result() as $row)  {
    $Player=$row->image;



    if($count<3)
    {
    echo '</div><div class="row">';
    $count=0;
    }else
    {
    $count++;
    }
       echo "<div class='col-sm-4'>";
        echo "<div class='news-v2-badge'><img class='img-responsive' style='' src='http://opunletter.com/" .  $Player . "'";
        echo "</div>";
          echo "<p><span>23</span><small>Jan</small></p>";
        echo "<div class='post-caption'>";
    echo "<ul class='post-inline block-grid-v1-add-info'>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> 34039</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-up'></i> 451</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-down'></i> 863</a></li>";
    echo "</ul>"; 

    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";


     echo "<div class='news-v2-desc'>";
                                   echo "<h3><a href='#'>Reading Some Books</a></h3>";
                                   echo "<small>By Admin | California, US | In <a href='#'>Art</a></small>";
                                  echo "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio.</p>";

                               echo "</div>";
                               echo "</div>";

    }
   echo '</div>';

         ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All it takes is one extra pixel of content height (in this case the height of the 2nd tile) and it starts to act as a new anchor for following floating elements (before they wrap).

Firstly, I'd add a specific class to the tile div:

```
 echo "<div class='col-sm-4 card-tile'>";
```

and then, in CSS, I'd specify two important things - fixed height and overflow:hidden, like this:

```
.card-tile {
    height:280px; /* feel free to change this to your liking of course */
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

You can also add padding if need be (to prevent the text touching the bottom edge) or you can truncate the description text. For this to work, though, you'll have to specify a fixed height for the text container (the P after the SMALL tag in your code) - here's the code to sum this up:

```
echo "<small>By Admin | California, US | In <a href='#'>Art</a></small>";
echo "<p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
```

and in CSS:

```
p.description {
    height:140px; /* again, feel free to change this */
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: if you modify the height of the column, the height may not be responsive.

Comment: That's true, it's probably the least evil way though... Making things responsive both horizontally AND vertically can be a huge issue and mostly not worth the effort. Point is, if you don't want to set a fixed height to the column, you'll have to figure out how to clear after every row...

Comment: Also, if he makes the page responsive, he'll most probably want to have a flexible number of columns, too, so you can't just wrap a fixed number of columns in a div...